# spotLightHelper not pointing to target when loaded from json scene

Tags: three.js

I am using the latest version of Three.js(82) and importing my spot light from blender exporter(json). I have the following code when looping over all the scene objects after loading:

```
// loop
if(object instanceof THREE.SpotLight){
    lightHelper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper(object);
    scene.add(lightHelper);                         
}
// after loop
spot = scene.getObjectByName("Spot",true);
spot.target = scene.getObjectByName("Cube",true);

// in render() funcition
lightHelper.update();
```

The spotlight helper shows up but it never points to the target. If I try to add  a spotlight to the scene manually, it works fine. I think it has to do something with the spotlight being in the child scene. Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

Comment: any messages in console log?

Comment: No errors, the spotlighthelper never move.

Comment: `console.log(scene.getObjectByName("Spot",true));` and `console.log(scene.getObjectByName("Cube",true));`. What results in console log?

Comment: The Spot will show the properties of the spotlight in the child scene and cube is in the child scene as well. So the structure is the root scene and the entire loaded json scene is added to the main scene. The lightHelper is attached to the main scene and is passed the Spot spotlight object.